# How to make own logical font in Java?

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I'd like to be able to merge a list of `java.awt.Font` into a single `Font` so that if a glyph for a given `char` can't be found in a font earlier in the list is will fall back to fonts later in the list to provide the glyph.  Is there any way to do this without having to muck around with the `sun.font` package?  And if `sun.font` is the only way to do it, then how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical fonts does not supposed to be manipulated by the application at runtime They intend to be configured by the Java runtime implementation, to supply the programmer with a set of cross platform font names that can be safely used by the application GUI.

See Sun's tutorial about [Physical and Logical Fonts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html).

Hence, configuring logical fonts is done on the runtime implementation side and is implementation dependent.
E.g., a quote from Sun's [Font Configuration Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html) guide:

> Sun's Java SE Runtime Environments use font configuration files to map logical font names to physical fonts. There are several files to support different mappings depending on the host operating system version. The files are located in the lib directory within the JRE installation. Users can edit or create their own font configuration files to adjust the mappings to their particular system setup. Note however that this is a modification of the JRE, and Sun does not support modified JREs.